# Can racial spell slots work with Sorcerer's Font of Magic & Flexible Magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, racial-traits, spell-slots

Can racial spell slots work with Sorcerer's Font of Magic & Flexible Magic?

EX: Can you use a tiefling's once a day Burning Hands Lv2 and convert it to 2 Sorcery Points? Can This work the other way around, restoring the tiefling's once a day Burning Hands Lv with 3 Sorcery Points?

Comment: what is a racial spell slot?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### This does not use spell slots so you cannot convert anything

The Infernal Legacy feature states:

> You know the thaumaturgy cantrip. When you reach 3rd level, you can cast the hellish rebuke spell as a 2nd-level spell once with this trait and regain the ability to do so when you finish a long rest. When you reach 5th level, you can cast the darkness spell once with this trait and regain the ability to do so when you finish a long rest. Charisma is your spellcasting ability for these spells.

You gain the ability to cast the spell, once. There are no spell slots involved at all, the spell is simply cast. I'm really not sure how to explain this further, but if there were any sort of spell slots involved, the feature would say so.

The following question exists which discusses racial spells and the fact that you cannot upcast them at all, the one after it explains that slots are not used with these, the next explains that you cannot even cast the spell using a spell slot (the exception is if you also learn it for your class which the final link goes over):

- [Do slotless racial spells improve at higher character levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113569)
- [Can you cast a racial spell if you do not have access to the spell slot required?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68809)
- [If you have the ability to cast a spell without a spell slot can you cast that spell using a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102875)
- [If you get a spell through a racial ability, can you also take it as a spell from a class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106114)